# Add a dedicated bot login to Stack Apps

Tags: feature-request, authentication

When dealing with chat bots, especially those like SmokeDetector, you'll often want to log in directly from the code. The problem? There's no easy way to do this, especially now that Open ID is being deprecated. There's now even a Captcha, which... kinda *is* hard for bots to solve ;)

To get around this issue, it would be nice to have a way to log in through the API or something (this isn't my area of expertise, so I don't know what I'm talking about). So, for instance, if Stack Apps were to have a route to have bots log in from (without captchas), and then that cookie would propagate to the rest of the network.

This would make working with a bot, especially if you're actively working on something and restarting (and so logging in) a lot, a whole lot easier.

Comment: The API *does* provide a means of logging in... For the API. The problem comes from wanting to do stuff that isn't in the API, right?

Comment: @Shog9 - Yes. I did mention that I don't know what I'm talking about ;)

Comment: As I dealed with a Java and a Python version of the Chat libs, just recieving that cookie (IIRC it's `acct`, but not sure) would suffice.

Comment: To clarify, *"Wanting to stuff that isn't in the API"*, this is normally enter and post message in chat rooms